Sum of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}P_n(x)$ where $P_n$ are Legendre polynomials
I'm working on this exercise:
Sum the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}P_n(x)$ for $|x|<1$ where $P_n$ are Legendre polynomials.
Computing some partial sums it looks like that series goes to $\tanh^{-1}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$. In my series there are only odd power of $x$ and only few term of the series can actually change the coefficient of $x^d$ because in the $n$-th therm there are only powers of $x$ from $x^{n+1}$ (actually $x^{n+2}$ if $n$ is odd) up to $x^{2n+1}$. To find a power series expression I tried to apply the Rodrigues formula and the Newton binomial:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}P_n(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\frac{1}{2^n n!}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\Big((x^2-1)^n\Big) = \\ = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\frac{1}{2^n n!} \frac{d^n}{dx^n} \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}x^{2k}(-1)^{n-k} = \\ = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\frac{1}{2^n n!} \sum_{k=\left\lceil\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rceil}^n \frac{(2k)!}{(2k-n)!}\binom{n}{k}x^{2k-n}(-1)^{n-k} $$
From here I have no idea about how to build a general method to compute the coefficient of $x^d$ for odd $d$. I tried some examples for some powers but even with numbers I can't find a general semplification that can help me. For example, the coefficient of $x^5$ comes from the fifth degree terms $n\in\{2,3,4\}$:
$\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{2^2 2!}\binom{2}{2}\frac{4!}{(4-2)!}(-1)^{2-2} + \frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{2^3 3!}\frac{4!}{(4-3)!}\binom{3}{2}(-1)^{3-2} + \frac{1}{5}\frac{1}{2^4 4!}\frac{4!}{(4-4)!}\binom{4}{2}(-1)^{4-2} = \\= \frac{1}{2}-\frac{3}{8}+\frac{3}{40} = \frac{1}{5} \checkmark$
There's a way to compute this in general? For odd degree $d=2\delta +1$ it seems to be
$$\sum_{k=\left\lceil\frac{\delta +1}{2}\right\rceil}^{2\delta +1} \frac{1}{k}\frac{1}{2^k k!}\binom{k-1}{\delta}\frac{(2\delta)!}{(2\delta -k)!}(-1)^{2\delta +1 +k}$$ and I don't even know how to start with something like this.
Otherwise, there is a better way to get the solution of a problem of this kind? Do you have some hints?

Note that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} P_n(x) = \int_0^x \sum_{n=0}^\infty P_n(x)t^n \,\mathrm{d}t,
$$
with
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty P_n(x)t^n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2xt+t^2}}
$$
being the ordinary generating function of Legendre polynomials, hence
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} P_n(x) = \int_0^x \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{1-2xt+t^2}} = \left.\ln\left(\sqrt{1-2xt+t^2} + t-x\right)\right|_{t=0}^{t=x} = \operatorname{arctanh}x.
$$

Thanks, this method is definitely way more easy and elegant.
